# IndexedDB data gets deleted automatically

Tags: angular, database, windows, indexeddb, dexie

I'm using dexie with Angular 11 to access indexedDB, sometimes what happens is indexedDB data gets deleted automatically and tables are empty.
It happens only with windows, in ubuntu or android it work fine.

I have not written any delete queries or script, still it gets deleted automatically.
One common thing that I have observed is, whenever data gets deleted automatically, it prints kind of message like `index db need to reopen db.`

Comment: do you mean "indexeddb" ?

Comment: @Random yes , indexeddb.

Comment: Maybe, try to open a connexion with IndexedDb each time you need to interact with this base. I have a similar issue with the CacheStorage and I have to open a connexion each time

Comment: I'm using dexie package with default configs so opening and closing of indexeddb will be handled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think that probably caused by browser update.
I've encountered the same problem with Chrome recently and my entire IDB data were gone for ever.
IndexedDB is a consensus that all browsers supposed to be support it and keep data for persistence.
But in real world, it seems not to be as it was to be.
Many geeks say, "don't rely on IndexedDB"
I can't agree more with that now.
But if I find a way to make IDB reliable, then it will give me far beyond opportunities.